# What is the latest technology for Client/Server network communication applications in .NET?

Tags: .net, networking, client-server, communication

I was recently charged with creating a Client/Server application where the Server waits for connections and the Client then connects to it, enabling these applications to communicate (send object instances, string messages, etc. to each other)
I was wondering what is the newest network technology suitable for such an application in the realm of .NET?

I haven't really worked with .NET since version 2.0 and am not sure what newer stuff have been introduced that would make it easier to create such Client/Server pairs.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Named pipes for low-level interop on the same machine, WCF replaced Remoting.  Sockets work like they always did.

Comment: This is open-ended; there are any number of valid answers... Service Stack for example

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at technologies like WCF or ASP.NET. 
using ASP.NET you can create such an application on the HTTP specification and REST APIs.